# PHP : curl is and Not working in ubuntu10.04 and Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, php, curl, nginx

I am running  Nginx server on ubuntu 10.04

I am using the php version 5.3.2  .I installed php5-curl using apt-get install php5-curl.

Unfortunately the curl package is not displaying in phpinfo() .

While executing functions it is saying that `call to undefined function curl()`

Please help what should I do in this case I am not able to figure out this .

Thanks

Is there any way to activate php curl ?